# How to conditionally render styled-component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Right now I have a menu with a list of `MenuItem` component:

```
          <MenuItem>A</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>B</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>C</MenuItem>
```

I want to style the component to only be visible when a boolean is true (like isLoggedIn) How do i do so? I dont want to manually add a condition to each menu item as I have a hundred

`` const PrivateMenuItem = styled.MenuItem` \\what to write here `; ``

```
          <PrivateMenuItem>A</PrivateMenuItem>
          <PrivateMenuItem>B</PrivateMenuItem>
          <PrivateMenuItem>C</PrivateMenuItem>
```

Comment: You can wrap all of them in a `<></>` and add boolean condition before that: `showThese && <><MenuItem>A</MenuItem><MenuItem>B</MenuItem><MenuItem>C</MenuItem></>`

Comment: Does this help? https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a component that handle it for you:

```
export default const PrivateMenuItem = ({show=true, children})={
  return show &&  <MenuItem>{children}</MenuItem>
}
```

If you want to hide it with styling you can use it like this:

```
export default const PrivateMenuItem = ({show=true, children})={
  return show ? 
          <MenuItem className={styles.show}>{children}</MenuItem> :
          <MenuItem className={styles.hide}>{children}</MenuItem>
}
```

and later you can use:

```
<PrivateMenuItem show={true}>A</PrivateMenuItem>
<PrivateMenuItem show={false}>B</PrivateMenuItem>
```